# Pass this to addEventListener() as parameter

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I want to add `change` event to a group of checkboxes, how can I access `this` in my event function, so that when I do the event I can access value of the checkbox.

This is my current code:

```js
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('cb');
Array.from(checkboxes).forEach(function(){
  this.addEventListener("change", cbChange(this), false);
});

function cbChange(ele){
  console.log(ele.value);
}
```

```html
<input class="cb" type="checkbox" name="candidate" value="1"/>
<input class="cb" type="checkbox" name="candidate" value="2"/>
<input class="cb" type="checkbox" name="candidate" value="3"/>
<input class="cb" type="checkbox" name="candidate" value="4"/>
```

Comment: What is `this` in the context of this code: `this.addEventListener`; it isn't the `current checkbox`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Inside the `forEach` callback, `this`  *does not* refer to a DOM element. It doesn't refer to any useful value.

Secondly, you are immediately calling `cbChange` and pass its return value to `addEventListener`, which is `undefined`. But `addEventListener` expects to be passed a *function*, so you either have to pass `cbChange` or a function that calls `cbChange`.

Lastly, while you could define the event handler to accept the element as first argument, it's much simpler if it accepts the *event object*, because that is the default API.

Having said all that, the simplest solution would be:

```
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('cb');
Array.from(checkboxes).forEach(function(element){
//                                      ^^^^^^^
  element.addEventListener("change", cbChange, false);
//^^^^^^^  
});

function cbChange(){
  console.log(this.value);
//            ^^^^
}
```

Since inside an event handler, `this` refers to the element the handler is bound to, using `this` inside `cbChange` just works.

---

And here are some alternatives:

```
// Use the event object
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('cb');
Array.from(checkboxes).forEach(function(element){
  element.addEventListener("change", cbChange, false);
});

function cbChange(event){
  console.log(event.target.value);
}


// Using a wrapper that calls `cbChange`
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('cb');
Array.from(checkboxes).forEach(function(element){
  element.addEventListener("change", function() { cbChange(this); }, false);
});

function cbChange(ele){
  console.log(ele.value);
}
```

Comment: can `call` be used to borrow `cbChange`?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. `call` would execute the function immediately, but it should be called immediately.

Answer (score 2):

you don't need to pass `this` to event handler. you can access `event.target` inside event handler. you can do something like this:

```js
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('cb');
Array.from(checkboxes).forEach(function(){
  this.addEventListener("change", cbChange, false);
})

function cbChange(event){
  var ele = event.target;
  console.log(ele.value);
}
```

```html
<input class="cb" type="checkbox" name="candidate" value="1"/>
<input class="cb" type="checkbox" name="candidate" value="2"/>
<input class="cb" type="checkbox" name="candidate" value="3"/>
<input class="cb" type="checkbox" name="candidate" value="4"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove `(this)` from `cbChange(this)`. This will immediately execute the function.

To get the value you need the `target`.`target` is the element on which event is executed.On consoling `ele` you will see all available options

```js
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('cb');
Array.from(checkboxes).forEach(function() {
  this.addEventListener("change", cbChange, false);
});

function cbChange(ele) {
  console.log(ele.target.value);
}
```

```html
<input class="cb" type="checkbox" name="candidate" value="1" />
<input class="cb" type="checkbox" name="candidate" value="2" />
<input class="cb" type="checkbox" name="candidate" value="3" />
<input class="cb" type="checkbox" name="candidate" value="4" />
```

Comment: Worth pointing out that this only works accidentally because the event handler is added to the global object. This would throw in strict mode.

Answer (score 1):

From my opinion, i thinks you can use for..of loop to get the value of each checkbox.

```
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('cb');
for (let checkboxe of checkboxes ) {
  checkboxe.addEventListener('change', () => {
      console.log(checkboxe.value)
  })
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use map

```js
const checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('cb');
const cbArr = Array.from(checkboxes)
cbArr.map((d) => {
  d.addEventListener("change", cbChange(d), false);
});

function cbChange(ele){
  console.log(ele.value);
}
```

```html
<input class="cb" type="checkbox" name="candidate" value="1"/>
<input class="cb" type="checkbox" name="candidate" value="2"/>
<input class="cb" type="checkbox" name="candidate" value="3"/>
<input class="cb" type="checkbox" name="candidate" value="4"/>
```

Comment: This is not correct, because `cbChange` is called immediately, not when the event is triggered. Besides, there is no point in using `.map` if you are not going to do anything with the return value. `.forEach` is much more appropriate in such a situation.

Comment: I didn't understood that he wanted the event to be triggered, sorry, but reguarding map is more efficient than froEach, forEach is a slayer on performances

Comment: What makes you think that? Besides, iterating over 4 elements will hardly be a bottleneck.