# How Can I Run JavaScript functions consecutively?

Tags: javascript

I'm working through https://javascript30.com Challenge 5. I've got the solution working, but am trying to 'upgrade' so that all 'open' panels will close before the new panel will open.

Anyway, more specifically, in this context, when a panel is clicked, I need `closeOpens()`to run. **After** that, I need the clicked on panel to proceed with opening, etc.

```
const PANELS = document.querySelectorAll('.panel');
/**
  * Look for open panels and close them.
*/
function closeOpens() {
  let opens = document.querySelectorAll('.open');
  console.log('hi'); // TODO: Doesn't display!

  // Close any 'open' panels first!
  if (opens.length > 0) {
    opens.forEach((o) => {
      o.classList.remove('open');
    });
  }
}

PANELS.forEach((panel) => {
  panel.addEventListener('click', closeOpens => {
  panel.classList.add('open');

  });

  panel.addEventListener('transitionend', e => {
    if (e.propertyName.includes('flex')) {
      e.target.classList.toggle('v-slide-in');
    }
  });
});
```

As indicated above, `console.log('hi');` is not running. The `'click'` event just proceeds to `...add('open)'`

For completeness, here's the rest of the markup and styles, but this is really just a JS issue:

```
<style>
    html {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      background: #ffc600;
      font-family: 'helvetica neue';
      font-size: 20px;
      font-weight: 200;
    }

    body {
      margin: 0;
    }

    *,
    *: before,
    *: after {
      box-sizing: inherit;
    }

    .panels {
      min-height: 100vh;
      overflow: hidden;

      display: flex;
    }

    .panel {
      background: #6B0F9C;
      box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      align-items: center;
      /* Safari transitionend event.propertyName === flex */
      /* Chrome + FF transitionend event.propertyName === flex-grow */
      transition: font-size 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.61, -0.19, 0.7, -0.11),
      flex 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.61, -0.19, 0.7, -0.11),
      background 0.2s;
      font-size: 20px;
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center;
      flex: 1;
      /* Split space amongst children */
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
    }

    .panel1 {
      background-image: url(https://source.unsplash.com/gYl-UtwNg_I/1500x1500);
    }

    .panel2 {
      background-image: url(https://source.unsplash.com/rFKUFzjPYiQ/1500x1500);
    }

    .panel3 {
      background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1465188162913-8fb5709d6d57?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=faces&cs=tinysrgb&w=1500&h=1500&fit=crop&s=967e8a713a4e395260793fc8c802901d);
    }

    .panel4 {
      background-image: url(https://source.unsplash.com/ITjiVXcwVng/1500x1500);
    }

    .panel5 {
      background-image: url(https://source.unsplash.com/3MNzGlQM7qs/1500x1500);
    }

    .panel>* {
      margin: 0;
      width: 100%;
      transition: transform 0.5s;

      flex: 1 0 auto;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }

    .panel>*:first-child {
      transform: translateY(-100%);
    }

    .panel.v-slide-in>*:first-child,
    .panel.v-slide-in>*:last-child {
      transform: translateY(0);
    }

    .panel>*:last-child {
      transform: translateY(100%);
    }

    .panel p {
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
      text-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.72), 0 0 14px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
      font-size: 2em;
    }

    .panel p: nth-child(2) {
      font-size: 4em;
    }

    .panel.open {
      font-size: 40px;
      flex: 5;
    }
  </style>

  <div class="panels">
    <div class="panel panel1">
      <p>Hey</p>
      <p>Let's</p>
      <p>Dance</p>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel2">
      <p>Give</p>
      <p>Take</p>
      <p>Receive</p>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel3">
      <p>Experience</p>
      <p>It</p>
      <p>Today</p>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel4">
      <p>Give</p>
      <p>All</p>
      <p>You can</p>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel5">
      <p>Life</p>
      <p>In</p>
      <p>Motion</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Don't see your `closeOpens()` method being called anywhere.

Comment: :| `panel.addEventListener('click', closeOpens => {` M I missing something?

Comment: There, `closeOpens` is the name you give to the event parameter that will be passed in to the event handler. It's not a method call.

Answer (score 3):

Simply, call `closeOpens()` inside the click handler. It will close the existing open panel and then open the clicked panel.

```
panel.addEventListener('click', () => {
  closeOpens();
  panel.classList.add('open');
});
```

```js
const PANELS = document.querySelectorAll('.panel');
/**
  * Look for open panels and close them.
*/
function closeOpens() {
  let opens = document.querySelectorAll('.open');
  console.log('hi'); // TODO: Doesn't display!

  // Close any 'open' panels first!
  if (opens.length > 0) {
    opens.forEach((o) => {
      o.classList.remove('open');
    });
  }
}

PANELS.forEach((panel) => {
  panel.addEventListener('click', () => {
  closeOpens();
  panel.classList.add('open');

  });

  panel.addEventListener('transitionend', e => {
    if (e.propertyName.includes('flex')) {
      e.target.classList.toggle('v-slide-in');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
html {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      background: #ffc600;
      font-family: 'helvetica neue';
      font-size: 20px;
      font-weight: 200;
    }

    body {
      margin: 0;
    }

    *,
    *: before,
    *: after {
      box-sizing: inherit;
    }

    .panels {
      min-height: 100vh;
      overflow: hidden;

      display: flex;
    }

    .panel {
      background: #6B0F9C;
      box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      align-items: center;
      /* Safari transitionend event.propertyName === flex */
      /* Chrome + FF transitionend event.propertyName === flex-grow */
      transition: font-size 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.61, -0.19, 0.7, -0.11),
      flex 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.61, -0.19, 0.7, -0.11),
      background 0.2s;
      font-size: 20px;
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center;
      flex: 1;
      /* Split space amongst children */
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
    }

    .panel1 {
      background-image: url(https://source.unsplash.com/gYl-UtwNg_I/1500x1500);
    }

    .panel2 {
      background-image: url(https://source.unsplash.com/rFKUFzjPYiQ/1500x1500);
    }

    .panel3 {
      background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1465188162913-8fb5709d6d57?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=faces&cs=tinysrgb&w=1500&h=1500&fit=crop&s=967e8a713a4e395260793fc8c802901d);
    }

    .panel4 {
      background-image: url(https://source.unsplash.com/ITjiVXcwVng/1500x1500);
    }

    .panel5 {
      background-image: url(https://source.unsplash.com/3MNzGlQM7qs/1500x1500);
    }

    .panel>* {
      margin: 0;
      width: 100%;
      transition: transform 0.5s;

      flex: 1 0 auto;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }

    .panel>*:first-child {
      transform: translateY(-100%);
    }

    .panel.v-slide-in>*:first-child,
    .panel.v-slide-in>*:last-child {
      transform: translateY(0);
    }

    .panel>*:last-child {
      transform: translateY(100%);
    }

    .panel p {
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
      text-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.72), 0 0 14px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
      font-size: 2em;
    }

    .panel p: nth-child(2) {
      font-size: 4em;
    }

    .panel.open {
      font-size: 40px;
      flex: 5;
    }
```

```html
<div class="panels">
  <div class="panel panel1">
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Let's</p>
    <p>Dance</p>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel2">
    <p>Give</p>
    <p>Take</p>
    <p>Receive</p>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel3">
    <p>Experience</p>
    <p>It</p>
    <p>Today</p>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel4">
    <p>Give</p>
    <p>All</p>
    <p>You can</p>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel5">
    <p>Life</p>
    <p>In</p>
    <p>Motion</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So, really, I can just do this... `panel.addEventListener('click', () => {
        closeOpens();
        panel.classList.add('open');
      });` Seems to work...

Comment: Great. I will review this in the morning with fresh eyes to make sure I get it. One thing though is instead of doing: `panel.classList.add('open');` why can't I use `this` or `e.target` instead of re-calling `panel.` I guess I am still confused about all the differences - will continue learning...

Comment: Yes you can do it, Check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44988614/pass-this-to-addeventlistener-as-parameter) Also, to pass `this`, you have to get rid of arrow function.

Comment: Oh...IDW to do that. I like 'fancy' arrow fxn. Makes me feel like I know what I'm doing! ;)

Comment: Then your best bet would be to use the `event` object. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have two functions to perform: closing all panels, and opening one. Start with the two tasks you need to perform and don't worry about the events yet.

```
function closePanels(){
    //do work
}

function openPanel(el){
    //do work
}
```

Now that you have the ability to do what needs doing, you can wire them up in a logical multistep task.

```
PANELS.forEach((panel) => {
  panel.addEventListener('click', function(){
        closePanels();
        openPanel(this);
  });
});
```

This way we've separated individual units of work from our specific complex task.

Comment: Yes, except, I didn't make an explicit openPanel fxn, as it's just 1 line of code. For stuff that's 1 line of code, I don't bother making fxn.

Comment: Consider that any verb/action you want to perform that is significant from an application perspective (not the total number of lines of code) is a good candidate for a function. Following this basic convention will make your code more intelligible and will extend and reactor better.